# Cleaning data in CSV files using dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to read a CSV (with header) file from GCS which has about 150 columns and then
1. Set column data for particular columns
2. Update NaN with Null values for all columns
3. Write the csv file (with header) to GCS

Here is the tricky part: processing is done on Cloud Dataflow which means i have to use Apache beam transforms to achieve this.
I have tried multiple ways like skipping_header_lines and using the schema

My pipeline code is:

```
def parse_method(self, line):    
    reader = csv.reader(line.split('\n'))
    for csv_row in reader:
        values = [x.decode('utf8') for x in csv_row]
        row = []
        for value in csv_row:
            if value == 'NaN':
                value = 'Null'
            row.append(value)
    return row

(p
    | 'Read_from_source' >> beam.io.ReadFromText('gs://{0}/test.csv'.format(BUCKET))
    | 'Split' >> beam.Map(lambda s: data_ingestion.parse_method(s))
    | 'Write_to_dest' >> beam.io.WriteToText(output_prefix,file_name_suffix='.csv', num_shards=1))
```

E.g.:
If my csv input contains;

name custom1   custom2
arun undefined Nan
dany losangels temporary

Expected csv;
name custom1   custom2
arun losangels Null
dany losangels temporary

Comment: Can you elaborate what kind of error you're getting?

Comment: Are you having trouble because the header is not discarded? Or what is happening to your files?

Comment: Hey Pablo, they are two issues, 1. files are printed as a list, 2. Change the value based on the column header read from the CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following produces the output you're looking for:

```
    lines = p | ReadFromText(file_pattern="gs://<my-bucket>/input_file.csv")

    def parse_method(line):
        import csv
        reader = csv.reader(line.split('\n'))
        for csv_row in reader:
            values = [x.decode('utf8') for x in csv_row]
            row = []
            for value in csv_row:
                if value == 'NaN':
                    value = 'Null'
                row.append(value)

        return ",".join(row)



    lines = lines | 'Split' >> beam.Map(parse_method)
    line = lines | 'Output to file' >> WriteToText(file_pattern="gs://<my-bucket>/output_file.csv")
```

Now for editing the columns based on the header I'm not sure if there is some more straightforward way, but I would use pandas the following way:

```
    lines = p | "ReadFromText" >> ReadFromText(file_pattern="gs://<my-bucket>/input_file.csv")

    def parse_method(line):
        import pandas as pd

        line = line.split(',')
        df = pd.DataFrame(data=[line],columns=['name','custom1','custom2'])
        df['custom2'] = df.custom2.apply(lambda x: 'None' if x == 'Nan' else x)
        values = list(df.loc[0].values)
        return ",".join(values)

    lines = lines | "Split" >> beam.Map(parse_method)
    line = lines | "Output to file" >> WriteToText(file_path_prefix="gs://<my-bucket>/output_file.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you, I am able to write to the CSV as expected. But the problem is to edit the file based on the columns. The header is read from the source