# Spanner to CSV DataFlow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-spanner

I am trying to copy table from spanner to big query. I have created two dataflow. One which copies from spanner to text file and other one that imports text file into bigquery.

Table has a column which has JSON string as a value. Issue is seen when dataflow job runs while importing from text file to bigquery. Job throws below error :

INVALD JSON: :1:38 Expected eof but found, "602...

Is there anyway I can exclude this column while copying or any way I can copy JSON object as it is? I tried excluding this column in schema file but it did not help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#cloud-spanner-to-cloud-storage-text there are options on BigQuery import jobs that would allow to skip columns, neither Cloud Spanner options that would skip a column when extracting.

I think your best shot is to write a custom processor that will drop the column, similar to [Cleaning data in CSV files using dataflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55661634).

it's more complicated but you can also try DataPrep: http://cloud/dataprep/docs/html/Drop-Transform_57344635. It should be possible to run DataPrep jobs as a DataFlow template.